# Android - Problems with Reading/Writing to Internal storage

Tags: android, file, input

I am developing an Android game. I have a Game class that extends View, and a Main Activity class.

I am trying to load a high score from the Internal storage. I want it to load in onCreate() and save in onDestroy().

```
Game game;
FileOutputStream fos;
FileInputStream fis;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    game = new Game(this);

    String collected = null;

    try {
        File file = getBaseContext().getFileStreamPath(Game.FILE_NAME);
        if(!file.exists()){
            file.createNewFile();
        }

        fis = openFileInput(Game.FILE_NAME);
        byte[] dataArray = new byte[fis.available()];
        while (fis.read(dataArray) != -1){
            collected = new String(dataArray);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            fis.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    if(collected != null) game.setHighScore(Integer.parseInt(collected));
    else game.setHighScore(0);
    setContentView(game);
    }

protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();

    try {
        fos = openFileOutput(Game.FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String data = "" + game.highScore;
        fos.write(data.getBytes());
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        try {
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}



}
```

I am testing the app on my DroidX. It crashes on startup while trying to read the file. If I comment out the section to read it, the app will run fine and write the data as it should. If I run again while the data is saved, it loads correctly.

How can I check to see if the file exists before trying to load it?

Thanks in advace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Switch over to using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html), it is designed for this use case.

Here's an example to illustrate how easy it makes it:

```
public class Example extends Activity {
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle state){
       super.onCreate(state);
       . . .

       // Restore preferences
       SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
       // Get highScore if it exists, otherwise default to zero
       int highScore = settings.getInt("highScore", 0);
       setHighScore(highScore);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop(){
       super.onStop();

      // We need an Editor object to make preference changes.
      // All objects are from android.context.Context
      SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
      editor.putInt("highScore", mHighScore);

      // Commit the edits!
      editor.commit();
    }
}
```